# Insert y Update en dos tablas en un solo Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Buen dia

Tengo un problema con el siguiente query ,
Mi intencion es Insertar datos y actualizar en una tabla y a su vez que se inserten ciertos
datos en otra tabla y así mismo cuando quieras actualizar un datos se actualice en las dos tablas.

El insert y update de la tabla General si funciona pero al momento de actualizar los datos no hace nada,Adjunto Coodigo:

Todos los datos son recopilados desde un formulario,por eso el uso de stores procedures:

Espero que me puedan ayudar de antemano Gracias(tuve que recortar los parámetros para que me dejara mostrar la estructura del codigo)

```
  Alter PROCEDURE SPI_Inventario 
            @IdEquipo int, 
            @Responsable nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Empresa nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Sucursal nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Ubicación nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Tipo nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Marca nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Modelo nvarchar(MAX), 
            @NoSerie nvarchar(MAX), 
            @Procesador nvarchar(MAX),                          
             AS BEGIN 
            /*SET NOCOUNT ON*/
            DECLARE @NewID INT 
             if exists(
                select 
                  IdEquipo 
                from 
                  General 
                where 
                  IdEquipo = @IdEquipo
              ) BEGIN 
             
            Update 
              General 
            SET 
              NombreCompletoResponsable = @Responsable, 
              Empresa = @Empresa, 
              Sucursal = @Sucursal, 
              Ubicación = @Ubicación, 
              Tipo = @Tipo, 
              Marca = @Marca, 
              Modelo = @Modelo, 
              NoSerie = @NoSerie, 
              Procesador = @Procesador 
                    
            
            WHERE 
              IdEquipo = @IdEquipo 
            
            END 
            ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO General (
                NombreCompletoResponsable, 
                Empresa, 
                Sucursal, 
                Ubicación, 
                Tipo, 
                Marca, 
                Modelo, 
                NoSerie, 
                Procesador
              ) 
            VALUES 
              (
                @Responsable, 
                @Empresa, 
                @Sucursal, 
                @Ubicación, 
                @Tipo, 
                @Marca, 
                @Modelo, 
                @NoSerie, 
                @Procesador 
               
              ) 
            
               if exists( select  IdEquipo  from UsuarioAsignado  where 
                  IdEquipo = @IdEquipo
              ) BEGIN 
             
              Update UsuarioAsignado SET 
            NombreCompletoResponsable = @Responsable, 
             Tipo = @Tipo, 
             Marca = @Marca, 
             Modelo = @Modelo, 
             FechaAlta = @FechaAlta, 
            FechaBaja = @FechaBaja 
            WHERE 
             IdEquipo = @IdEquipo 
             END
             ELSE BEGIN
            
            SELECT 
              @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
            set 
              identity_insert UsuarioAsignado ON;
            INSERT INTO UsuarioAsignado (
              IdEquipo, NombreCompletoResponsable, 
              Tipo, Marca, Modelo, FechaAlta, FechaBaja
            ) 
            VALUES 
              (
                @NewID, @Responsable, @Tipo, @Marca, 
                @Modelo, @FechaAlta, @FechaBaja
              )
            END 
            END
            END
```

Comment: buen día, primero que nada te recomiendo trabajar en la identación, por que tal como esta el código es muy difícil de entender.

Comment: Y lo que veo en tu sp, es que haces una validación para si existe en tu tabla `General` que actualice, en caso contrario que lo inserte, y dentro de tu else para el insert es donde tienes la funcionalidad de actualizar a tu segunda tabla `UsuarioAsignado`, deberías dejarla fuera el segundo `if exists` de la primera condición para que siempre se ejecute.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea Gracias por tu ayuda , Tomare en cuenta lo de identificacion y seguire tus indicaciones